# Unable to create spring boot initialzr project (A org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException exception has occurred)

Tags: windows, netbeans, docker, spring-boot, microservices

I have been following this guide but is unable to create a springboot project: 
https://jaxenter.com/playing-with-spring-boot-docker-in-netbeans-ide-127672.html

I get the following error when I'm trying to create a springboot project:

```
Caused: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request; nested exception is 
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:700)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:653)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:628)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:590)
    at com.github.alexfalappa.nbspringboot.projects.initializr.InitializrService.getMetadata(InitializrService.java:68)
    at com.github.alexfalappa.nbspringboot.projects.initializr.InitializrProjectWizardPanel1.getInitializrMetadata(InitializrProjectWizardPanel1.java:122)
[catch] at com.github.alexfalappa.nbspringboot.projects.initializr.InitializrProjectPanelVisual1.construct(InitializrProjectPanelVisual1.java:332)
    at org.openide.util.AsyncInitSupport.run(AsyncInitSupport.java:168)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1443)
    at org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.GlobalLookup.execute(GlobalLookup.java:68)
    at org.openide.util.lookup.Lookups.executeWith(Lookups.java:303)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2058)
```

I'm using the following tools:
Docker toolbox for windows
, NetBeans IDE Build 201701260001
, Oracle VM VirtualBox 5.1.4 (latest version)
, nb-springboot-1.4

Docker seems to run smootly without any problem so I don't think the problem lies there.
On the other hand, netbeans docker services container and images are empty but I'm able to connect to the service.
Docker quickstart terminal:

```
Running pre-create checks...
Creating machine...
(default) Copying C:\Users\Hung\.docker\machine\cache\boot2docker.iso to C:\Users\Hung\.docker\machine\machines\default\boot2docker.iso...
(default) Creating VirtualBox VM...
(default) Creating SSH key...
(default) Starting the VM...
(default) Check network to re-create if needed...
(default) Waiting for an IP...
Waiting for machine to be running, this may take a few minutes...
Detecting operating system of created instance...
Waiting for SSH to be available...
Detecting the provisioner...
Provisioning with boot2docker...
Copying certs to the local machine directory...
Copying certs to the remote machine...
Setting Docker configuration on the remote daemon...
Checking connection to Docker...
Docker is up and running!
To see how to connect your Docker Client to the Docker Engine running on this virtual machine, run: C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker-machine.exe env default



                        ##         .
                  ## ## ##        ==
               ## ## ## ## ##    ===
           /"""""""""""""""""\___/ ===
      ~~~ {~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~ /  ===- ~~~
           \______ o           __/
             \    \         __/
              \____\_______/

docker is configured to use the default machine with IP 192.168.99.102
For help getting started, check out the docs at https://docs.docker.com

Start interactive shell

Hung@DESKTOP-7MFR98J MINGW64 ~
$
```

Update: I was not able to solve the problem, but was able to create spring boot project from http://start.spring.io.

Comment: Is this your method: `com.github.alexfalappa.nbspringboot.projects.initializr.InitializrService.getMetadata` ?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think so. It doesn't seem to be able to execute the plugin.